# How to avoid a flat density line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, kernel-density, density-plot

I'm trying to plot a density line over 2 overlapped histograms, but with every code I use, the line gets "flat".

I have to create two histograms, each with a normal distribution, and a different number of samples. Then I have to overlap both and write the density line. All with ggplot2 package.

This is what I've tried:

```
xx<-data.frame(dat = rnorm(n, mean, sd))
yy<-data.frame(dat = rnorm(n, mean, sd))
both<-rbind(xx, yy)

ggplot(both, aes(x=dat)) + 
    geom_histogram(data = xx, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2,binwidth=0.25) + 
    geom_histogram(data = yy, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2, binwidth=0.25) +
    theme_light() +
    geom_line(data=samples, stat = "density")
```

I also tried `geom_density` but the result is the same...

Comment: Please can you edit the question to include some sample data (you can use `dput(sample1)`). Best strategy is probably to combine sample1 and sample2 with `dplyr::bind_rows` and add `fill` to the `aes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density line is not flat, it's simply on a very different scale with respect to the histograms, since, by default, the histogram is created using counts on the y-axis.

You should specify `y = after_stat(density)`:

```r
# packages
library(ggplot2)

# data
set.seed(1)
sample1 <- data.frame(dat = rnorm(10000, 0, 1))
sample2 <- data.frame(dat = rnorm(15000, 3, 1))
both <- rbind(sample1, sample2)

ggplot(both, aes(x = dat)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), data = sample1, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2, binwidth = 0.25) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), data = sample2, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2, binwidth=0.25) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_line(stat = "density")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The black line represents a sort of a mixture of the two normal distributions. You should read the help page of the `after_stat` function for more details.

Comment: I get an error, saying `Error in after_stat(density) : could not find function "after_stat"`although `library(ggplot2)` is activated

Comment: The function `after_stat()` was introduced in version 3.3.0 of `ggplot2` (see the first bullet point of the New features section here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news/news.html). If you can, I think you should update the package, otherwise you can use the older approach, i.e. `y = stat(density)` or `y = ..density..`.